# scraping wikipedia table - list of U.S. Senators

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to create a table where I can get the list of all U.S. Senators from the 116th Congress [from the following wikipedia webpage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_senators).

As of now, I am using the following code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
#import censusdata

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_senators"
page = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features = 'html.parser')
table=soup.find("table", class_="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter")
# print(table)
state=[]
senator=[]
party=[]
born=[]
assumed_office=[]
term=[]

for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    col=row.find_all('td')
    col1=col[0].string.strip()
    state.append(col1)
    col2=col[2].string.strip()
    senator.append(col2)
    col3=col[3].string.strip()
    party.append(col2)
    col4=col[4].string.strip()
    born.append(col4)
    col5=col[7].string.strip()
    assumed_office.append(col5)
    col6=col[8].string.strip()
    term.append(col6)

columns={'State':state,'Senator':senator,'Party Affiliated':party,'Birth Date':born,'Assumed Office':assumed_office,'Next Election':term}

df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
print(df)
```

However, I ended up getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\file_path\US Senate.py", line 23, in <module>
    for row in table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

All I want to do is get the following data from each column: Name, the State the senator is representing, party affiliate, Age, when did they assume office, and when is their next election. Any assistance on this is truly appreciated.

Comment: what is the content of `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `pd.read_html`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
#import censusdata

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_current_United_States_senators"
page = requests.get(url).content

dfs = pd.read_html(page)

df = dfs[4]

df['Residence'] = [elem.split('[')[0] for elem in list(df['Residence'])]
df = df.drop('Image', axis = 1)
df['Party'] = df['Party.1']
df = df.drop('Party.1', axis = 1)

df.to_csv('D:\\senators.csv', index = False)
```

Screenshot of `csv` file (I've done a bit of formatting so that it looks neat):

[image]